# Spring Batch : commit interval while reading a directory

Tags: xml, spring, spring-batch

I am using spring-batch `chunk oriented step` to read a directory of XML files, process and write to data base. My `commit interval is 1` so in each chunk/iteration the reader will read one XML file from the directory.

In processor, I am `unmarshaling` the read XML file and sending it to writer. However everything is working fine but the XML file may contain millions of records which I want to commit in batches i.e. I want to commit the file data let us say for every 10,000 records.

How to achieve this by configuration or any other approach??

Cheers,
Shanky

Comment: What `ItemReader` are you using?  The `StaxEventItemReader` reads XML in item by item so there's no need to manually do the unmarshalling in the processor.  If you can share your configuration, we'll be able to provide a better answer.

Comment: More clear explanation of the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29129056/spring-batch-multiresourceitemreader-vs-commit-interval