# Spring-batch MultiResourceItemReader vs commit-interval

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-batch, jobs

I am using spring-batch MultiResourceItemReader to read a directory of XMLs and delegating it to StaxEventItemReader.

The commit-interval on the chunk acts on MultiResourceItemReader i.e. the commit happens for each XML.

I want to make the commit-interval act on StaxEventItemReader so that I can commit my huge XML data in chunks instead of one XML at a time.

Any help?

Comment: The behavior you're describing isn't the expected behavior with Spring Batch so can you please provide your configuration?  `commit-interval` is based on the item (what's returned from the reader) so using the `MultiResourceItemReader` shouldn't have an impact on that.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelMinella : your comment made me clear on what I am doing wrong. I fixed the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Can you suggest me how to make the commit on every file/resource the MultiResourceItemReader is reading??

Problem: let us say I am processing country.xml having 33 records and city.xml having 5 records using MultiResourceItemReader. and my commit-interval is 10.

so, first 3 commits will contain country.xml data where as the last commit contains 3 country + 5 city data.

Comment: You'd need a custom `CompletionPolicy` to accomplish that.  You can read more about the `CompletionPolicy` interface in the documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/repeat/CompletionPolicy.html